How to correctly refer, in typescript, to variable field name in json structure
There is an API that returns this kind of json:
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'name1',
    ingredient1: 'ingredient1',
    ingredient2: 'ingredient2',
    ingredient3: ''
}

When looping through a response which is an array of the JSON above, I want to pick up all the ingredients and put them in an array. But typescript doesn't really like the way I do it and shows an error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DrinkResponseType'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'DrinkResponseType'.

export type DrinkResponseType = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    ingredient1: string;
    ingredient2: string;
    ingredient3: string;
}
const drinks: Array<DrinkResponseType> = response.drinks;
drinks.forEach((item: DrinkResponseType) => {
    let all_ingredients: Array<string> = [];
    for(let i=1;i<=3;i++){
        const label = `ingredient1${i}`;
        const value = item[label];
        if(value){
            all_ingredients.push(value);
        }
    }
    console.log(all_ingredients);
})  

If I add // @ts-ignore before the label declaration, I can make it work.
But it still looks like there should be a better way to avoid this error.

You can use a bunch of array methods to avoid object property access. As a bonus you can add more ingredient props to the type and code will adapt. If you need more strict prop name matching just use a regex like ^ingredient\d+$
Playground
type DrinkResponseType = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    ingredient1: string;
    ingredient2: string;
    ingredient3: string;
}
const drinks: Array<DrinkResponseType> = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'name',
  ingredient1: 'salt',
  ingredient2: 'paper',
  ingredient3: ''
}];

const all_ingredients = drinks.
  flatMap(drink => Object.entries(drink)
  .filter(([k, v]) => k.startsWith('ingredient') && v)
  .map(([_, v]) => v));
  
console.log(all_ingredients);



The problem is that your fori loop can't resolve the bounds of the loop at compile time. You can resolve this by iterating a const array instead, see this playground link
type DrinkResponse = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  ingredient1: string;
  ingredient2: string;
  ingredient3: string;
}

declare const drinks: DrinkResponse[];

for (const drink of drinks) {
  const ingredients: string[] = []

  for (const i of [1, 2, 3] as const) {
    const key = `ingredient${i}` as const
    const value = drink[key]

    if (value) {
      ingredients.push(value)
    }
  }
}


Building on Alexander's solution, as long as your JSON is not nested you can use an interface DrinkResponseType { [key:string]: string }; in place of a type.  Then your key(s) can be anything, and since your loops are looking for 'ingredient', the code can adjust to any keys you add.
interface DrinkResponseType { [key:string]: string };
const drinks: Array<DrinkResponseType> = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'name',
  ingredient1: 'salt',
  ingredient2: 'paper',
  ingredient3: ''
}];

const all_ingredients = drinks.
  flatMap(drink => Object.entries(drink)
  .filter(([k, v]) => k.startsWith('ingredient') && v)
  .map(([_, v]) => v));
  
console.log(all_ingredients);

hth, adym

The point was to have strongly typed fields, which this does not accommodate. You would then have to do symbol shenanigans to restore such functionality.

Understood, but I see no mention of strongly typed fields except your comment.
